# Google Maps APIv2 app not working, keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, runtime-error, google-maps-android-api-2

Im having trouble getting my map to display on an Android App. I have watched videos and read many forums (including this one) on troubleshooting the issues. My code isnt displaying any errors but every time I run it whether it be on an phone, tablet or emulator it says "Unfortunately, stuff has stopped". Any help or assistance would be greatly appreciated. SN: SDK and Google Play Services are up to date.

### MainActivity.Java

```
package com.stuff;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (googleMap == null) {
    googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) 
    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    if (googleMap != null) {
        setUpMap();
    }
 }
}

private void setUpMap() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
        getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, 
        longitude)).title("You are here!"));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

### Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.stuff"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission             android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
 <!-- The following two permissions are required for location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
          android:value="AIzaSyAQz_W-qNqgpXp8SZG3sqAt_YuVVSalCg8"/>
    <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
          android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

### LogCat

```
07-25 01:54:10.266: E/Trace(1074): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-25 01:54:11.085: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1074): Google Play services is missing.
07-25 01:54:11.085: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1074): Google Play services is missing.
07-25 01:54:11.105: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1074): Google Play services is missing.
07-25 01:54:11.105: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1074): Google Play services is missing.
07-25 01:54:11.117: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1074): Google Play services is missing.
07-25 01:54:11.117: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1074): Google Play services is missing.
07-25 01:54:11.145: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1074): Google Play services is missing.
07-25 01:54:11.165: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1074): Google Play services is missing.
07-25 01:54:11.208: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1074): Google Play services is missing.
07-25 01:54:11.325: D/AndroidRuntime(1074): Shutting down VM
07-25 01:54:11.325: W/dalvikvm(1074): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-25 01:54:11.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1074): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 01:54:11.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1074): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.stuff/com.stuff.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-25 01:54:11.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-25 01:54:11.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-25 01:54:11.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-25 01:54:11.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-25 01:54:11.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-25 01:54:11.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-25 01:54:11.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-25 01:54:11.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 01:54:11.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-25 01:54:11.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-25 01:54:11.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-25 01:54:11.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 01:54:11.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1074): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-25 01:54:11.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at com.stuff.MainActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded(MainActivity.java:33)
07-25 01:54:11.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at com.stuff.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
07-25 01:54:11.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-25 01:54:11.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-25 01:54:11.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-25 01:54:11.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     ... 11 more
07-25 01:54:11.536: D/dalvikvm(1074): GC_CONCURRENT freed 140K, 9% free 2701K/2960K, paused 19ms+4ms, total 216ms
07-25 01:54:13.585: I/Process(1074): Sending signal. PID: 1074 SIG: 9
```

Comment: I solved the issue this website has a more detailed explanation https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Maps-Fragment-Guide

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed Google Play Services using sdk manager?

Comment: would that throw a `NullPointerException`. `getMap()` returns null.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getMap()` returns null.

> public final GoogleMap getMap ()
>
> Gets the underlying GoogleMap that is tied to the view wrapped by this
>   fragment.
>
> Returns the GoogleMap. Null if the view of the fragment is not yet
>   ready. This can happen if the fragment lifecyle have not gone through
>   onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) yet. This can also
>   happen if Google Play services is not available. If Google Play
>   services becomes available afterwards and the fragment have gone
>   through onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle), calling this
>   method again will initialize and return the GoogleMap.

So you need to wait till fragment is ready and also check for availability google play services before initialing GooleMap object.

Comment: How exactly would I go about doing that, because I dont quite understand what you mean in reference to the Fragment life cycle?

Comment: @user3875336 read http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html. Yes look at the fragment lifecycle and activities

Comment: @user3875336 look at **Ensure Devices Have the Google Play services APK** it he link

Comment: @user3875336 could also read **Check for Google Play Services** @ http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: Google play services is installed on my physical devices

Comment: @user3875336 wait till the fragment is ready. read fragment lifecycle. That's all it will work

Answer (score 1):

try to change you layout to this:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

or

```
if (googleMap == null) {
    googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
SupportMapFragment mFragment;
     mFragment = new SupportMapFragment() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
                    if ((map = mFragment.getMap()) != null) {
                        setUpMap();
                    }
                }
            };
```